# How to play video in full screen focus on TabBar item in tvos

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uitabbarcontroller, tvos, apple-tv

I am developing  app for apple tv in swift.I have set TabBar hidden property  to false show TabBar. I need to apply auto video play when I navigate to this video page i.e. focus should be on TabBar item and video should auto start.

Additionally when navigating from TabBar to currently playing video then video should become in full screen and TabBar should hide.

If then I press menu button then it should show TabBar again with focus on it and video still playing in restore screen.

If you have any suggestion then share it with me.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a single tap gesture on the player and play it full screen by passing the Video URL to a method using the same steps you followed to play the video. Present a video player on tap gesture. It works